# How to call controller's event after async treatments on the run part?

Tags: angularjs

I look for a user's session in the run process, and i would like to open a modal if i got a specific information from the User.

The thing is i need to send the scope to the modal, so i have to open it from a controller.

The problem is, when angular load controller, the user is not logged yet.
I tried to `$location.path('/');` after the run async process, but it doesn't call the `indexCtrl` twice (because i am already on the view he is binding).

So my question is, how could i "refresh" my controller at the `User.getSession() callback` or how could i approach the thing differently ?

```
angular.module('TEST').run(function($rootScope, $window, AuthenticationManager, $location) {
    AuthenticationManager.getSession(function() {
        $location.path('/'); //Unfortunately useless because it doesn't call the indexCtrl twice
    });
};

angular.module('TEST').controller('indexCrtl', function($scope, $User) {
    if ($User.nb_points === 10) //Not fired because the user is not logged at the first load
        var Modal = $modal({scope: $scope, show: false, template: 'modal.html'});
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`$route.reload()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/%24route%22)

> Causes $route service to reload the current route even if $location
>   hasn't changed.
>
> As a result of that, ngView creates new scope, reinstantiates the
>   controller.

[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/5y8AN/1/)